# Jupyter Lab extension @jupyterlab/git installation issue

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

### Background

I want to install git extension for Jupyter Lab. As suggested [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git/blob/master/README.md), I used the following commands:

```
pip install --upgrade jupyterlab-git
jupyter lab build
```

Following that the outcomes of the checking commands are as follows:

```
(base) neeraj@neeraj-personal:~$ jupyter serverextension list
config dir: /home/neeraj/.jupyter
    jupyterlab_git  enabled 
    - Validating...
      jupyterlab_git 0.21.1 OK
config dir: /home/neeraj/Documents/0_anaconda3/etc/jupyter
    jupyterlab  enabled 
    - Validating...
      jupyterlab 2.2.6 OK
    jupyterlab_git  enabled 
    - Validating...
      jupyterlab_git 0.21.1 OK
    nbdime  enabled 
    - Validating...
      nbdime 2.0.0 OK
```

and

```
(base) neeraj@neeraj-personal:~$ jupyter labextension list
JupyterLab v2.2.6
Known labextensions:
   app dir: /home/neeraj/Documents/0_anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
        @jupyterlab/git v0.21.1  enabled  OK
        @jupyterlab/latex v2.0.1  enabled  OK
        @jupyterlab/toc v4.0.0  enabled  OK
        jupyterlab-recents v2.0.0  enabled  OK
```

### Problem

The Git panel is not visible. How to address this, or are there any other steps or dependencies that I am missing?

### Other information

There are no error messages when starting Jupyter Lab. Following are the messages.

```
jupyter lab
[I 08:43:23.622 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /home/neeraj/Documents/0_anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 08:43:23.622 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /home/neeraj/Documents/0_anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab
[I 08:43:23.837 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/neeraj
[I 08:43:23.838 LabApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.1 is running at:
[I 08:43:23.838 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=b2f0f43a667bf02d5dd6909b54142c31264d676921cea5f6
[I 08:43:23.838 LabApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=b2f0f43a667bf02d5dd6909b54142c31264d676921cea5f6
[I 08:43:23.838 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 08:43:23.938 LabApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/neeraj/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-5762-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=b2f0f43a667bf02d5dd6909b54142c31264d676921cea5f6
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=b2f0f43a667bf02d5dd6909b54142c31264d676921cea5f6
[I 08:43:33.879 LabApp] Build is up to date
[I 08:44:51.796 LabApp] Kernel started: 63592d97-9dfd-4c9b-a5dc-adaec553f7b9, name: python3
```

Comment: Are there error messages while juputerlab is starting ?

Comment: @qrtt1: No error messages, I have updated the question to include the messages at the beginning.

Comment: Any messages in the browser (developer) console?

Comment: No error messages in the browser either.